# Can you run functions inline if else in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code that has a long conditions inside inline if else in react, can i make it short by putting a function inside inline statement?

I tried doing this and it gives me an error "discount is not defined"

```
  function getDiscount(props) {
    const discount = props.discount;
    discount.map((discounts, i) => {
      if (condition) {
        return;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    })
  }

{props.discount ? <getDiscount discount={discount} /> : <b>No available discount</b>}
```

Comment: yes why not ? you can

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: Where are defining this function or inline condition? Is it a stateless functional component?  Can you show the whole component as you wrote it when it didn't work?

Comment: Please provide a code sample. This does not really help to answer your question.

Comment: Also you must return something from your functional component otherwise nothing will be displayed in place of <getDiscount>

Answer (score 1):

While passing discount to the `getDiscount` component, you need to pass it from the props like

```
{props.discount ? <getDiscount discount={props.discount} /> : <b>No available discount</b>}
```